# Apache 2.4.7 goes down

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a Directadmin server with Apache 2.4.7 without reason it goes down (maybe a bug)

Some logs:

```
[Wed Feb 19 08:16:48.801505 2014] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 23327] (38)Function not             implemented: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Feb 19 08:16:49.179768 2014] [core:alert] [pid 30295] AH00050: Child 23327 returned  a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Wed Feb 19 08:16:55.660600 2014] [core:notice] [pid 30295] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

I not showing you double errors because they the same, anyone see what goes wrong ?

In php.ini:

> zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so >zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/ZendGuardLoader.so

Answer (score 4):

Apache can use multiple mutex (a type of a lock) handling technologies. It seems, that the actually used locking mechanism is buggy in your apache version, or is incompatible with your actual mpm.

The easiest way to use some other. You can change this with the `AcceptMutex` directive in the apache config. The possible values are (copied from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mpm_common.html ):

```
AcceptMutex flock
AcceptMutex fcntl
AcceptMutex posixsem
AcceptMutex pthread
AcceptMutex sysvsem
```

In your case looks `sysvsem` or `posixsem` optimal, but any other directive can also work.

Comment: I use Apache 2.4 so i have add: Mutex posixsem